# How to show the tooltips on different placements in Python Plotly/Dash Rangeslider?

Tags: python, plotly, plotly-dash, plotly-python, rangeslider

I have a RangeSlider and I'm showing the values on tooltips. But the tooltips are on the same placement and both seem to be intertwined as seen in the picture below. I want to show the tooltips on different placements. For example, left tooltip must be on top placement and right tooltip must be on bottom placement. Is this possible?

[image]

```
dcc.RangeSlider(id={"type": "slider-1", "index": n_clicks},
                min=335.2, max=7830.6, slider_value=[4461.2,4817.6]
                tooltip={'always_visible': True, 'placement':'bottom'},
                step=0.1)
```